# how to enclose sub-string into square brackets python

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I have a very long text with parts enclosed in +++ which I would like to enclose in square brackets

```
se1 = "+++TEXT:+++ Moshe Morgenstern is on his way to the main synagogue in the center of Bnei Brak, home to a largely ultra-orthodox - or haredi - community. +++ : Bnei Brak, Tel Aviv + Jerusalem ))+++"
```

I would like to convert text enclosed in +++ to [[]] so,

```
+++TEXT+++ should become [[TEXT]]
```

My code:

```
import re


se1 = "+++TEXT:+++ Moshe Morgenstern is on his way to the main synagogue in the center of Bnei Brak, home to a largely ultra-orthodox - or haredi - community. +++ Karte Israel mit: Bnei Brak, Tel Aviv + Jerusalem ))+++"

comments = re.sub(r"\+\+\+.*?\+\+\+", r"[[.*?]]", se1)
print(comments)
```

but it gives the wrong output

```
[[.*?]] Moshe Morgenstern is on his way to the main synagogue in the center of Bnei Brak, home to a largely ultra-orthodox - or haredi - community. [[.*?]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
re.sub(r'\+\+\+(.*?)\+\+\+',r'[[\1]]',se1)
```

As the `.*?` in the second string is seen as pure string instead of the replacement for the `.*?` in the match string, the `(.*?)` means to save this part to be used in the replacement string, and `\1` is the data saved.

Answer (score 1):

You need to capture the group with `()` and then reference that matching group with `\1`

This should work fine:

```
>>> comments = re.sub(r"\+\+\+(.*?)\+\+\+", r"[[\1]]", se1)
>>> comments
'[[TEXT:]] Moshe Morgenstern is on his way to the main synagogue in the center of Bnei Brak, home to a largely ultra-orthodox - or haredi - community. [[ Karte Israel mit: Bnei Brak, Tel Aviv + Jerusalem ))]]'
```

Take into account that `\+\+\+` can be simplified to `\+{3}` as well.